# confidence interval when both $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are unknown

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I have the following problem in my problem book:

Let $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ where both $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are unknown. I have to find a confidence interval for the mean.

What I have so far:

I know that when $\sigma^2$ is unknown I can use t-distribution for finding a confidence interval, i.e.:
$$\bar x \pm t_{n-1}^*\frac{s}{\sqrt{n}},$$

where $t_{n-1}^*$ is a t-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom and $\bar x$ is the sample mean from a sample of size $n$.

The whole problem seems kind of vague to me. Is this enough for describing the confidence interval? I don't know the sample mean $\bar x$ so is it okay to describe the solution in such a way?

Comment: If you don't know $\bar x$ and $s$, probably the expression is what is being asked!!

Comment: @satishramanathan still I thought there's something I don't know. thanks!

Comment: The way you have stated the problem is vague. You speak of a sample of size $n,$ but before that you appear to think you've stated what the problem is although you didn't say anything in that part about a sample of any size. If you have an i.i.d. sample of size $n,$ then the confidence interval is the one you give, so you're done. If the problem is actually to _derive_ that interval, then you have more work to do. But I can't tell from what you wrote whether that's what you need to do. So far, it is not clear what question you are asking.

Comment: @MichaelHardy That's because the problem didn't say anything about sample size. What I've stated after the problem as "What I've got so far" is my knowledge which is for a sample size and sample mean. I have literally rewritten the problem. I don't know how the problem cannot be vague and the rewriting be vague. Thanks!! I'll add an edit that's the actual problem in my problem book and not something I'm just trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the standard deviation is unknown but the distribution is Gaussian, the trick is to use the fact that the reduced variable

$$\bar t:=\frac{\bar x-\mu}{\sqrt{\dfrac{s^2}n}}$$ where $s^2$ is the corrected variance follows a Student's distribution (of $n-1$ dof).

Knowing the probability of this variable to be in a certain range, you have your confidence interval for $\mu$.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot! So I use this test statistic, check the table for a desired probability and then express the inequality in terms of $\mu$?

Comment: @NikolaShahpazov: exactly. This is the formula that you wrote.